# Create rules in CLIPS and template person

Tags: clips

Template Person

a. Define a template for person, contains full name, children names

b. Define a rule that prints the parents that have more than 3 children

c. Define a rule that print the parent of a certain child

The specified child name will be asserted in a fact called (child-name <name>)

i dont know how to check if the person have more than 3 children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **parent** deftemplate with a **child-names** multislot, then the following pattern will match any parent with more than 3 children:

```
(parent (childs-names $?names&:(> (length$ ?names) 3)))
```